# Collapse data ranges and overlapping data in SQL Server 2014

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a table with ranges in it as below:

```
ID  ActionCode  Group1  Type    Low         High
33  A           840     MM      000295800   000295899
34  A           840     MM      000295900   000295999
```

I need to collapse the two rows with consecutive data into one row for instance above would be

```
ActionCode  Group1  Type    Low         High
A           840     MM      000295800   000295999
```

For the ActionCode, Group1, Type...

There can be overlapping data ranges, preceeding zeros, etc.

Sample Table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TestTable

CREATE TABLE #TestTable(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ActionCode] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Group1] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Type] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [Low] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [High] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_#TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)  
) 

GO

INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','JJ','401299870','401299879')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','AA','401644000','401646999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','JJ','401378000','401378999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','JJ','401644000','401646999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','JJ','401299970','401299979')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','JJ','400424000','400424999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','JJ','401299990','401299996')
-- Ds
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('D','840','JJ','401198000','401198999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('D','840','JJ','401649000','401649999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','JJ','401299997','401299997')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('D','840','JJ','401376000','401390999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','JJ','401655000','401668999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','JJ','400411000','400411999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('D','840','JJ','400414000','400414999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','JJ','401646000','401646999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('D','840','JJ','400413000','400413999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','JJ','401654000','401654999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','GG','522892000','522892999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','GG','522892100','522892199')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','GG','522892400','522892999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','AA','522892400','522892999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','AA','522892300','522892399')
-- Different Types overlap range
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','AA','522892200','522892999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','KK','522892000','522892999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','KK','522892200','522892999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','KK','522892300','522892399')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','KK','522892400','522892999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','KK','522892100','522892199')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','GG','522892200','522892999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','GG','522892300','522892399')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','AA','522892100','522892199')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','356','AA','522892000','522892999')
-- Leading Zeros
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','MM','000295800','000295899')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','MM','000295900','000295999')
-- Overlap
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','NN','623295800','623295999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','NN','623295900','623295999')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','NN','623295900','623296099')
INSERT INTO #TestTable (ActionCode, Group1, Type, Low, High) VALUES ('A','840','NN','623296100','623296299')
GO


SELECT * FROM #TestTable ORDER BY Low
```

I can do this with a small table using recursive CTE, but the table has a little less than a million rows. But once I get over a certain size it takes a long time to run. There is an index on the "grouped" columns.

There must be a way to do this quickly, I'm just hitting roadblocks.

^

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  ActionCode,
            Group1,
            [Type],
            Low,
            High,
            next_low =  LEAD(low,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ActionCode,Group1,[Type] ORDER BY ID),
            next_high = LEAD(high,1) OVER (PARTITION BY ActionCode,Group1,[Type] ORDER BY ID)
    FROM #testTable
)

SELECT  ActionCode,
        Group1,
        [Type],
        Low,
        High
FROM CTE
WHERE       low != next_low 
        AND high!= next_high
```

Comment: Almost, not quite, for instance the Type NN should collapse into 623295900 and 623296299. I think you're on the right track... I'll try to work on this... I think this is a good stepping stone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption that your Low / High are all integers, so may need slight adjustments to what you consider high and low.

I'm also going to kick off with pretending I didn't see the contiguous part, in which case a simple group handles it:

```
SELECT
    ActionCode
    ,Group1
    ,Type
    ,min(convert(int,Low)) AS Low
    ,max(convert(int,High)) AS High
FROM #TestTable
GROUP BY
    ActionCode
    ,Group1
    ,Type
```

Assuming you did mean for each contiguous group based on ID, this becomes a classic "gaps and islands" problem which can be resolved with a row number compared to the ID:

```
;WITH Src AS
    (
        SELECT
            *
            ,ID-ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ActionCode, Group1,Type ORDER BY ID) AS ContiguousGroupID
        FROM #TestTable
    )

SELECT
    ContiguousGroupID
    ,ActionCode
    ,Group1
    ,Type
    ,min(ID) AS LowerIDBound
    ,max(ID) AS UpperIDBound
    ,min(convert(int,Low)) AS Low
    ,max(convert(int,High)) AS High
FROM Src
GROUP BY
    ContiguousGroupID
    ,ActionCode
    ,Group1
    ,Type
ORDER BY
    ContiguousGroupID
    ,ActionCode
    ,Group1
    ,Type
```